# Регулярное выражение для поиска ФИО python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Мне на вход подаются строки типа: 'Иван Иванов', 'Ирина', 'Dmitry Glebov', 'Каримов Валентин Иванович' и мне нужно регулярное выражение для проверки ФИО на корректность (корректно введённым ФИО считается ФИО на кириллице, в котором содержится хотя бы имя и фамилия)Я только начал изучать регулярные выражения и написал это      `'[а-яА-Я]{2,3}'` , но оно может принять, например, строку 'Никита', как мне переделать это выражение? Или это выражение не правильно в корне?

Comment: `re.fullmatch(r'[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+\s+[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+(?:\s+[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+)?', text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем варианте `[а-яА-Я]{2,3}` вы задаете строки, состоящие из 2 или 3 символов кириллицы. Вам же нужно задать два-три слова неограниченной длинны на кириллице. В частности у вас не хватает пробельных символов и спецификаторов повтора символов. Может выглядеть примерно так, как указал [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182013/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1150248/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%a4%d0%98%d0%9e-python#comment1992812_1150248)

```
[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+\s+[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+(?:\s+[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+)?
```

Comment: в фамилии иногда бывают дефисы (или все таки короткое тире?).

Comment: Тогда добавьте к диапазону символов еще и экранированный символ дефиса `[А-ЯЁ][а-яё\-]+\s+[А-ЯЁ][а-яё\-]+(?:\s+[А-ЯЁ][а-яё\-]+)?`. Если вы получаете данные в виде обычного текста, то скорее всего будет именно дефис, а не тире. Ну и еще можно использовать такие ресурсы, как https://regex101.com/ для тестирования выражений

Comment: Извините, что отвлёк, но у меня имена и фамилии могут начинаться и с маленькой буквы. Я сделал такой вариант `([А-ЯЁ]|[а-яё]+[А-ЯЁ]|[а-яё])+\s+([А-ЯЁ]|[а-яё]+[А-ЯЁ]|[а-яё])+(?:\s+([А-ЯЁ]|[а-яё]+[А-ЯЁ]|[а-яё])+)?` . Можно ли сделать это лучше?

Comment: Как я уже писал, регулярку всегда можно улучшить. Тут главное определить границы разумной достаточности, иначе спустя пару месяцев она может быть длинной под пару тысяч знаков, а разобраться в ней уже никто не сможет.

Comment: А как можно это улучшить? Ну сделать менее... монструозным что ли... При этом не потеряв в достаточности. Это возможно?